# Git ignoring .gitignore file in parent directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a structure like this:

```
projects/
    .gitignore
    foo/
        some_file
    bar/
        another_file
```

`foo`, `bar`, *and* `projects` are git projects. In `.gitignore` I have `*` (actually I tried loads of things), however when I run `git status` inside `projects/foo` it still tells me to add `some_file`. If I'm reading the `.gitignore` documentation correctly it says Git should look in all parent folders for `.gitignore` files and use those. However it seems to totally ignore the one in `.gitignore`. What is going on here?

I've tried `git check-ignore` and it just behaves as if the `.gitignore` did not exist.

To reproduce:

```
/ $ cd /tmp
/tmp $ mkdir projects
/tmp $ cd projects
/tmp/projects $ echo "*" > .gitignore
/tmp/projects $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/projects/.git/
/tmp/projects $ mkdir foo
/tmp/projects $ cd foo
/tmp/projects/foo $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/projects/foo/.git/
/tmp/projects/foo $ touch some_file
/tmp/projects/foo $ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    some_file

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Are you sure the `.git/` directory is in the right place?

Comment: Which `.git/` directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git only use rules in `.gitignore` file **in the currect repository**. You may want to symlink or hard link the `.gitignore` file from parent directory to all subdirectories if you want it to apply to all sub repositories.

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021) clarifies the `.gitignore` detection:

See [commit e041706](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e04170697a2848189492d53c7b3aab59c32d044f) (06 Jul 2021) by [Andrew Berry (`deviantintegral`)](https://github.com/deviantintegral).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bb3a55f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb3a55f6d32c86a25104097254b6fb8c5c3b7977), 22 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e04170697a2848189492d53c7b3aab59c32d044f): .gitignore parsing is to the top of the repo
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Andrew Berry</sup>

> The current documentation reads as if `.gitignore` files will be parsed in every parent directory, and not until they reach a repository boundary.
> This clarifies the current behaviour.
>
> As well, this corrects 'toplevel' to 'top-level', matching usage for 'top-level domain'.

`gitignore` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e04170697a2848189492d53c7b3aab59c32d044f/Documentation/gitignore.txt#L30-L34):

> Patterns read from a `.gitignore` file in the same directory
> as the path, or in any parent directory (up to the top-level of the working
> tree), with patterns in the higher level files being overridden by those in
> lower level files down to the directory containing the file.
>
> These patterns
> match relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file.

Since you initialize a nested Git repository in `/private/tmp/projects/foo/.git/`, the `.gitignore` in `projects/` will be -- itself -- ignored .

Answer (score 0):

Oh... it only reads them [up to the top level of the git repository](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level files *(up to the toplevel of the work tree)*

Poorly worded but ok.